# How to see aws ec2 instance cpu and memory utilisation without compute optimizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Compute optimizer shows right sizing recommendations for ec2 instances that have been active for a large period of time over the last 2 weeks. Through this it produces graphs that show you your cpu, memory and network usage from 0 to 100% of the instance capacity.

How do i get access to this information without the use of compute optimizer. I want to know so i can right size instances after 3 days instead of waiting for 2 weeks for compute optimizer to get enough data to produce a recommendation. I have tried with cost explorer but can't see any way to filter ec2 instances by cpu or memory utilisation.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances by default check a few baseline stats in 5-minute intervals which you could increase to "Enhanced Monitoring" that run checks every minute.

CPU is monitored by default and you can see it in the console if you go to EC2, your instance, and click the monitoring tab that shows up. To track memory you'll need to install the CloudWatch agent on the EC2 instance (second link).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring_ec2.html